# Check if an app has been opened and recive some alert about it

Tags: java, android

I’m working on an app that can "disable" another apps for a limited time. In the first activity the user can choose which application he wants to disable, then my application needs to check if the chosen apps have been opened. If so, my app needs to detect it and show the “disabled app” activity of my app instead.

My problem is how my app can detect that the disabled app has been opened.
I looked for solutions and found [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo) one and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) one, but they were removed.

Thank you!

Comment: Short answer: it can't, because such a feature could be abused.

Comment: Well there do exist apps that for example lock other apps with a passcode which work just like this but they need to be device administrator.

Answer (score 0):

There is an API you can use to query events about apps (packages) but it requires an additional 'special access' permission . Have a look at [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager)

Comment: First of all, Thank you! Secondly, by using `isAppInactive` I need to check after every period of time and I'm afraid it's a could be a burden to the phone.